# Parse GoogleMarker Coordinates i.e Lat and Long

Tags: c#, asp.net, parsing, google-maps

Hey I am I receiving a string values as such "(53.32000501118541, -6.223390102386475)"

How can I parse this string to seperate the 2 values and remove the "(" and ")"

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a simple replace of the brackets and then split by the comma.

```
String[] coords = "(53.32000501118541,-6.223390102386475)"
.Replace("(",String.Empty).Replace(")",String.Empty).Split(',');
```

This will give you a string array containing the 2 values you want.

```
coords[0] will == "53.32000501118541"
coords[1] will == "-6.223390102386475"
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you get a GLatLng value and you would like to extract lat and lng. You can use the lat() and lng() functions to do that, without parsing and extracting data from the string.